# Show that $\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dydx=9\pi$ in cartesian coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying solve this double integral by changing the order of integrals, but I could not, because the integral resulting is not elementary. I know that this integral is easy to solve when you changing the coordenates. Someone can help me giving me a trick or a equivalent integral. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From cartesian  to  polar coordinates $\to dxdy=rd\theta dr=d\theta rdr,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=r$

Change integration limits:$\int_{-3}^{3}dx \int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}dy \to \int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta
\int_{0}^{3}rdr$

$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dydx$
=$\int _{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{3}r^2drd\theta=\int _{0}^{\pi} 9d\theta=9\pi$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case I must demonstrate that by Cartesian coordinates. As you did it in a correct and very easy way to do it, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome -:)